# IFTTT Applet Creation with maker

Tags: ifttt

Can IFTTT applets be configured to perform multiple actions. for example can it be configured to have multiple presets. If i have Alexa linked and the IFTTT applet set to send stings to a server is there a way to say "Alexa trigger preset{presetnumber}"?  or do i have to make multiple applets?

Comment: You're in luck. IFTTT's Maker tier has this. It's free.
https://platform.ifttt.com/maker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the short answer (as far as I know) is no. It is possible to create an applet where you can say "alexa, trigger preset abc" and then, using the Maker applet, have that send a web request to a server/REST API, which you could have configured to connect to multiple different services through your own code.

Comment: IFTTT's free Maker tier (like other platform partners) now support multiple actions.

Comment: Wow, didn't actually know they do that now! Thanks for letting me know Eric! Definitely will be using that in the future!